# css3 rotate animation -- start to spin, then stop on frame

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have tried to create a function that will start a spin - then an image replace then a stop spin.

When I remove the spin class though -- it jolts - how do I stop the spinning but on a frame.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.image').addClass("spinner");
}, 400);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.image').removeClass("spinner");
}, 1500);
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

base code
http://jsfiddle.net/m6z4jgdq/

current example
http://jsfiddle.net/m6z4jgdq/2/

Comment: setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1500); should be set to 1400. Your animation starts after 400ms and lasts for 1000ms.

Comment: is there a more controlled way though of setting these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your image spin only once by removing the `infinite` iteration count in your CSS animation so that it only runs once:

```
.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s linear;
  animation: spin 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  animation-delay: 400ms; /* start animation after 400ms */
}
```

This way, there is no need to manually stop it from spinning, as it will naturally stop after is has rotated 360° (removing the "jolt" that appears). You can also add `animation-delay` if you want to start the animation after `400ms` instead of using JS and `setTimeout`:

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s linear;
  animation: spin 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image spinner" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

You can specify the iteration count (ie: how many times your animation repeats) by specifying it in the `animate` CSS style. For instance, if you want it to spin three times you can do:

```
animation: spin 1s linear 3;
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear 3;
  -moz-animation: spin 1s linear 3;
  animation: spin 1s linear 3;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image spinner" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

If you want a delay between each spin, then you need to specify keyframes which don't do anything, and extend your animation time such that it accounts to the delay as well:

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
}

.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear 3;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear 3;
  animation: spin 2s linear 3;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  50%, 100% { /* 50% of 2secs = 1sec, so 1 sec delay between rot */
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  50%, 100% { /* 50% of 2secs = 1sec, so 1 sec delay between rot */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  50%, 100% { /* 50% of 2secs = 1sec, so 1 sec delay between rot */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image spinner" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```